# within a project can I compile a module and interactively load the compiled module within ghci?

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghc, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

Typically in a Haskell project, I either work interactively with ghci or compile the entire project with cabal build.

However, in some use cases, I may have a computationally intensive routine along with some higher level scripting functionality, say for picking inputs to an analysis algorithm.

Is it possible to use GHCi + GHC such that I compile the computationally intensive module, load the compiled code to re-run with different inputs from within GHCi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can load compiled modules in ghci; if there is an appropriately named `.hi` and `.o` file, ghci will use those instead of interpreting the code in the corresponding `.hs` file. You will then only have access to the operations that are exported from that module.

In case you find yourself using a compiled loaded module when you wanted the interpreted one, you can `:load *foo.hs` to instruct ghci to ignore the compiled version and interpret `foo.hs`.